# Active Directory with Apache

Tags: apache, dll, active-directory, single-sign-on

I've a **Win2008-r2** server with an Active Directory domain.
I installed an Apache server on the same machine too.

Now I would like to do **SSO authentication** within this Web-server.

**mod_auth_kerb** is the "state-of-art" to achieve that.

I may be wrong, but on http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/ I noticed the module fits well under Linux, but I didn't see any convenient way to use it under Windows.

Is there an official way to compile it with MSVC?

Is there another alternative module more "Windows compliant"?

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of setting this up myself in a Linux environment. I think you need to use mod_authnz_ldap.
See this link.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html